# rendering has not updated after componentdidmount,advice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building an application to save locations i.e countries cities regions etc. When clicking on my on click function the states of two div tags change changing the class name and making one invisible and one visible.  advice?

```
import React, { useState }from "react";

import Area from "../ReadFolder/geographicMainComponents/areaMainComponent.jsx";
import City from "../ReadFolder/geographicMainComponents/cityMainComponent.jsx";
import Country from "../ReadFolder/geographicMainComponents/countryMainComponent.jsx";
import Neighborhood from "../ReadFolder/geographicMainComponents/neighborhoodMainComponent.jsx";
import Region from "../ReadFolder/geographicMainComponents/regionMainComponent.jsx";
import { default as AreaW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/areaMainComponent.jsx";
import { default as CityW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/cityMainComponent.jsx";
import { default as CountryW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/countryMainComponent.jsx";
import { default as  NeighborhoodW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/neighborhoodMainComponent.jsx";
import { default as  RegionW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/regionMainComponent.jsx";


export default function MenuWrapper({type,id,isEdit}){
   let [edit,setEdit] = useState(isEdit);
   let changer=()=>{console.log('you clicked me!');setEdit(!setEdit)}
       if(type==='country'){
            return(  
                     <div key={"frommenulist"+id}>
                        <div className={edit ? 'd-block' :'d-none'}><CountryW id={id}/><button onClick={changer}>read</button></div>
                        <div className={edit ? 'd-none' : 'd-block'}><Country id={id} /><button onClick={changer}>edit</button></div>
                     </div>
                     );
       }
       
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to work out what clicking those buttons is meant to do. It looks like you need only one div/button block, and clicking the edit button determines what happens (ie to make the country editable somehow).

At the moment it looks like you want to set the display to either `block/none` but you can't set an element's display to none and still expect to be able to click the button to reset the display because there will be no button to click on. Further: unless the `type` is "country" the component doesn't return *anything* so you need a condition in there to return *something* if `type` isn't "country" (or add a condition in the parent component to prevent the component rendering at all if that condition is met).

Here's a small example that uses local state to manage whether the div is a plain one or an editable one. Click the `edit` button, and then click in the div to be able to edit it. You can then click the `read` button to switch off `contentEditable` and keep the content.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function MenuWrapper({ type, id }) {

  const [ edit, setEdit ] = useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
    setEdit(!edit);
  }
  
  // Return a default div if type is not "country"
  if (type !== 'country') return <div>Not country</div>

  const divStyle = [
    'country',
    edit && 'edit'
  ].join(' ');

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div
          className={divStyle}
          contentEditable={edit}
        >Country Id: {id}
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>
          {edit ? 'Read' : 'Edit'}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MenuWrapper type="country" id="1" />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.country { padding: 0.25em; }
.edit { border: 1px solid green; }
button { margin-top: 1em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```